# Resource ID is always 0 using getIdentifier()

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.listitem_exercise_image) {
            String image_1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.d("MyApp", "image_1 = " + image_1);
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(image_1 , "drawable", getPackageName());
            Log.d("MyApp", "image_1 id = " + String.valueOf(resourceId));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Now, in the logs, it is showing this for my `Log.d`:

```
12-30 23:34:04.995: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 = abdominal_4_point_drawing_in_1.png
12-30 23:34:05.015: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 id = 0
12-30 23:34:05.165: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 = alternate_hammer_curl_1.png
12-30 23:34:05.195: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 id = 0
12-30 23:34:05.325: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 = alternate_incline_dumbbell_curl_1.png
12-30 23:34:05.335: D/MyApp(8354): image_1 id = 0
```

Now all of those .png files exist in the "drawable" folder. They DEFINATELY are in that folder. I know this because I was the one who dropped them into that folder, and I also just double checked. I also ran a Project Clean.

So why is the resource ID coming up as 0 for every single one?

Comment: Hmm, deleting your old question to re-post it is frowned upon. You should have added the new data to your existing question. Glad you found an answer though and now I understand why it didn't work.

Comment: thanks but i narrowed down the reason and felt it warranted a new question...ill try editing in the future next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource identifiers don't end with `".png"`, the extensions are stripped and some other transformations are done. Now if `image_1` where `"abdominal_4_point_drawing_in_1"` and there is a resource that generates a `R.drawable.abdominal_4_point_drawing_in_1` it would work.

Comment: ... Darn it. By two seconds. TWO SECONDS. +1, sir. :P

Comment: using `image_1 = image_1.replace(".png", "");` fixed it. thanks.